# How to create an external Hive table if the field value has comma separated values

Tags: hive, sqoop

I had used sqoop-import command to sqoop the data into Hive from teradata. Sqoop-import command is creating a text file with comma(,) as the delimiter.

After Sqooping, I had created an external table as shown below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
salary String, description String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

But description column has values like this:"abc,xyz,mnl". Due to this,loading of data into a hive table is not proper. Then how to create a text file with a delimiter other than comma while sqooping.

Then how to delimit the fields while creating an external table of Hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--fields-terminated-by` in your Sqoop job if you want to avoid the default delimiter.

`--fields-terminated-by` -  This parameter is used for field separator character in output.

Example: `--fields-terminated-by |`

and then change fields separator in create table statement by  `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘|’`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It worked fine for me.